# File upload not working correctly with PDF Converter

Tags: php, file-upload, uploadify, livedocx

Hi I am using LiveDocX to convert .Doc Files to .PDF files upon user upload.

However the files returned from LiveDocX are blank.

I seem to think this has somthing to do with the template path (file being uploaded through the form)

Below is the code in question.

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$tmpPath = '/CMS/Custom/vault/tmp/'.md5($_REQUEST['ID']).'/';

$targetPath = '/CMS/Custom/vault/'.md5($_REQUEST['ID']).'/';
$targetFile =  $targetPath . md5(time());

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fname = substr($filename, 0,strrpos($filename,'.')); 


$fi = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$ext = $fi->file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$extention = end(explode('.', $filename));

// IF DOCUMENT IS PDF

if(strstr($ext, "pdf")){
    $tmpFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/CMS/Custom/vault/tmp'.md5($_REQUEST['ID']);
    exec('convert '.$tempFile.' -resample 300 '.$tmpFile);
    $tempFile = $tmpFile;
}

// IF DOCUMENT IS DOCX

if ($extention == 'docx') {

        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/CMS/Custom/ZendFramwork/library/Zend/Service/docx';
        require_once $path.'/common.php';

        $docx = new Zend_Service_LiveDocx_MailMerge();

        $docx->setUsername(DEMOS_ZEND_SERVICE_LIVEDOCX_USERNAME)
             ->setPassword(DEMOS_ZEND_SERVICE_LIVEDOCX_PASSWORD);

        $docx->setLocalTemplate($tempFile);

        $docx->assign('dummyFieldName', 'dummyFieldValue'); // necessary as of LiveDocx 1.2

        $docx->createDocument();

        $document = $docx->retrieveDocument('pdf');

        if(!is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$tmpPath)){
            mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$tmpPath, 0755, true);
        }

        $pdf = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$tmpPath.$fname.'.pdf';

        file_put_contents($pdf, $document);

        unset($docx);

        $tempFile = $pdf;
        $filename = $fname.'.pdf';
}

// CREATE VAULT DIRECTORY.  

if(!is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$targetPath)){
    mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$targetPath, 0755, true);
}

//CREATE MD5 FILE

$file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$targetFile, "w+");


if(fwrite($file, convert(file_get_contents($tempFile), md5($_REQUEST['ID'])))){

    $targetFile = str_replace('/CMS/Custom/vault/', "", $targetFile);

    $q = "INSERT INTO `member_vault` SET `member` = '{$_REQUEST['ID']}', `name` = '{$filename}', `ext` = '{$ext}', `path` = '{$targetFile}', `time` = '".time()."'";

    mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

    unlink($tempFile);

    echo $targetFile;
}

}
```